# How to tell if the given set example is true or false

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I a have a set, for example:

`Let A = {1,{2,3},4}`

does `1,{2,3} ∈ A` and `{1,{2,3}} ⊆ A` both true?

I'm not sure about my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are true, $1,\{2,3\}$ is an element of A and $\{1,\{2,3\}\}$ is a subset of A, but $1,\{2,3\}$ would not be a subset of A, it would be only an element then, you need to notice if the left hand side is a set or not

Comment: Okay, Thank you!